# drop event not working in javascript , used preventDefault() but it's not working

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to create some drag and drop elements but the problem is drop event is not working.

- I used `event.preventDefault()` but it's not working yet.
- Tried onDrop inline but didn't work.
- Tried other browsers and didn't work.

I read all of the answers about drag and drop issues but they didn't work for me.

```js
const drag1 = document.querySelector(".drag-span-1");
const drop1 = document.querySelector(".drop-span-1");
const mainDiv = document.querySelector(".main-div");

drop1.addEventListener("drop" , (e)=>dropFunc(e , "span"));
drag1.addEventListener("drop" , (e)=>dropFunc(e , "span"));

function dropFunc (e , mode) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e , "drop" , mode)
}
```

```css
.main-div{
    display: flex;
    width: 95vw;
    height: 95vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.drag-span-1{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.3rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: grab;
}
.drop-span-1{
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="./test.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-div">
        <span class="drag-span-1" draggable="true">
            drag 1
        </span>
        <span class="drop-span-1">
            drop 1
        </span>
    </div>
<script src="./test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) is a good drag & drop instructional.

Comment: @RobMoll thanks a lot. I found my answer. In addition to `drop` event , I had to add `preventDefault()` to `drag` event.